# The use of seem

Tags: verbs

‘It seemed that they had visited the place before’ should be changed to a sentence starting with ‘They seemed’. I came up with They seemed to have had visited the place before, but am not sure whether it is correct

Comment: I wouldn’t go as far as to call it ungrammatical, but you’re not likely to hear any native speakers say it with the extra _had_.

Comment: I think I would have said "They seemed to recollect having visited the place before".

Comment: The first sentence of this question is unclear: *why* should it be changed that way? While it is possible to say 'They seemed . . .', its meaning is not quite the same as that of 'It seems . . .'; the former implies that there is something about *them* that creates the appearance, while the latter doesn't.

Answer (score -1):

Merram-Webster's Dictionary gives the idiom 'so it seems':
—used to say that one thinks that something is true.
"Are we on schedule?" "So it seems.
It is used instead 'We seem to be on schedule.